# Django postgres jsonfield filter error: Unsupported lookup

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am using DJango(version 2.0.6) and postgres(version 9.6). I have a table sp_users. The model has following fields:

> {
>         "name": "abc",
>        "age":30,
>         "gender":"male",
>         "address":{
>         "city":"Gotham",
>         "state":"xyz",
>         "country":"mno"
>         }
>      }

I am trying to filter table sp_users based on city, using the following code:

> SpUsers.objects.filter(address__city='Gotham')

here SpUsers is the model which maps to above table. I get the following error:

> Unsupported lookup 'city' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.

In the model i have defined address field as follows:

> address = JSONField(null=True, blank=False, default=dict)

What am i missing here? How to resolve this issue? I am able to filter based on field like name or age.

The model code is as follows:

```
class SpUsers(models.Model):
user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
address = JSONField(null=True, blank=False, default=dict)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user_id

class Meta:
    db_table = 'sp_users'
```

Comment: Can you share the actual relevant model code and the concrete value of the JSONField?

Comment: please upload your model

Comment: i have uploaded the model

Comment: The address value that i have provided is test data, which is similar to actual data